# Wordpress - How to Pass request value via URL

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to pass a parameter to a wordpress page. I don't want to pass it as a query string. I would like to pass as a slash based url.

Example

http://localhost/mysite/city?des=tn

To

http://localhost/mysite/city/tn

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to do this? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code, so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to use a custom query var and add a rewrite rule.

See [this question and the answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48487/how-to-retrieve-get-variables-from-rewritten-urls) for an example.

"To be added on init" means you should put this in an action hook that runs on the init event, like so

```
function addCityVar() {
// ....
}
add_action("init", "addCityVar");
```